# MPMoviePlayerController in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to get a mp4 movie to play in a UICollectionViewCell.  I'm having no luck getting it to display.  So, my first question is: Is this possible?  If so, what am I doing wrong?  It's a non-ARC project and I'm not using any XIBs or storyboards...

```
NSURL * theURL = nil;
NSBundle * bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
if (bundle)
{
     NSString * thePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"intro" ofType:@"mp4"];
     if ( thePath )
     {
         theURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:thePath];
     }
}

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: theURL];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player.view setFrame: self.contentView.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
[self.contentView addSubview: player.view];
[player play];
[player release];
```

Comment: Hold the player in an @property and check this. Do not release it after play.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you're releasing the player so it's being deallocated.

Comment out the last release and see if that fixes it.  If so, you'll need to save the reference away somewhere (member ivar/property of the cell?) and release it later.

Comment: I don't know if that will fix it: the `release` call will decrement the retain count, but he's already added the player as a subview, so the retain count won't be zero and hence won't be released until the player leaves the superview. I agree releasing there isn't good, but there might be something else at play.

Comment: he added the player view as a subview.  that doesn't hold the player controller in memory.